# NSString contents changes from orginal text during object creation

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsstring

This is the best reduced case of I am seeing

```
NSString * test = @"??( ";
NSLog(@"'%@'", test);

console> '['
```

I have a work around

```
NSString * test = @"\x3f\x3f(";
NSLog(@"'%@",test);

console> '??('
```

It seems like this is likely caused by string interpolation or similar process in the NSString object vivification. I'm posting this question for two reasons.

1) anyone happen to know what is actually causing this?
2) I didn't find anything on this 'feature' of NSString and it took me an hour to track down the bug, so this is just a bread crumb for future programmers. Using the hex code for the character was the work around.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? Which iOS version are you building for?

Comment: xcoode 6.1 ios6 (but I've seen it in other ios versions)

Comment: It's really hard to diagnose since it isn't reproducible in Xcode 6.1 / iOS 8.

Comment: Sense the point of this was mainly as a bread crumb, I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

`NSlog("'%@'", test);` is syntactically incorrect. How are you compiling it with this syntax error?

If I change it to `NSLog(@"'%@'", test);`, it works correctly (note the string literal denoting @ and the uppercase L in NSLog).

Comment: remus speaks truth (voted). NSLog expects and NSString literal as it's first parameter. That's a double-quoted string prefixed with an @ sign. A string with just double-quotes is a C string, which is a simple null-terminated array of bytes. The two are not interchangeable, and you should have gotten a compiler warning.

Comment: While this statement is true (typo in my example). It does not speak to the actual question. But thanks for catching the typo

Comment: @Nathan really hard to tell, since doing it properly I can't reproduce your issue...